# Stack based Object not Copied to heap if you send retain message to it?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, copy, objective-c-blocks, retain

Stack-based object will not be copied to the heap if you send it a `retain` message; it will only be copied upon receipt of the `copy` message.Please explain.

Comment: This only applies to blocks, not all "objects". Which part do you not understand?

Comment: @newacct, means what retain does so that it won't copy to heap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most objects are allocated on the heap, and their lifetime is determined by how many retains and releases they get. But blocks are a special kind of object that is normally allocated on the stack. This means that when the stack frame is popped (e.g. when your function returns), the memory for the block will be open to overwriting. Sending a stack-based block `retain` will not turn it into a heap-based object, so it will still be open to overwriting even if you retain it. The only way to keep the block around past the function's end is to `copy` it, which puts the copy on the heap.

Comment: "so it will still be open to overwriting even if you retain it. " it will not or will be i am confuse here?

Comment: @Sandy: Once the stack frame is popped, anything that was in that stack frame **will be** open to overwriting, whether you sent it retain or not. The thing is just that normal objects do not live on the stack.